# Show help when no target is specified

Tags: python, scons

In a number of Makefiles I've worked with, the default target was to simply display a list of targets that can be made. E.g.

```
$ make
Available targets:
    foo        Make the foo thing
    bar        Make the bar thing
```

Is this possible in SCons?

I've found the [`Help()`](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14195248) function for specifying the help text, but this only applies when you invoke `scons -h`.

And I've found the [`Default()`](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14443336) function specifying the default targets.  However I can't mange to hook everything up so that if you just type `scons` it will print the help text.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You can use the variable COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS (see SCons' MAN page), which usually contains the targets as specified on the command-line (but not via the Default() option). Just check for zero targets like this:

```
if not COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS:
    print_available_targets()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Awesome. I'll try this soon.

Answer (score 1):

We use something like the following (which uses `Default()`):

```
# Setup the default Help message
Help("""
Build binaries:

 $ scons program      # build the program

Run all unit tests:

 $ scons unittests

Options:
""")

# Append descriptions for the command line options
Help(command_line_vars.GenerateHelpText(env))

# Ensure that no default targets exist, so you have to specify a target.
# Give some help about what targets are available.
def default(env, target, source): print SCons.Script.help_text
Default(baseEnv.Command('default', None, default))
```

Note that `baseEnv` and `command_line_vars` are set prior to this section.